# PowerShell upload to S3 works inconsistently

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3

I'm having my weirdest issue to date and we are quite helpless right now.
We have Script A which calls multiple Scripts. The called Scripts return data to Script A as an Object and Script A uploads the collected data to some places including a S3 Bucket.
This works perfectly for called Script B, C, D, E, F,.... All uploading daily since I implemented the upload.
But some called Scripts can't upload all the time.

The Error I'm getting is:

```
No credentials specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults.
```

I have created the Profile with:

```
Set-AWSCredential -AccessKey ... -SecretKey ... -StoreAs MyProfile
```

In Script A I have:

```
Import-Module <fullpath>
Set-AWSProxy -Hostname <IPAddress> -Port 80
Initialize-AWSDefaultConfiguration -Region <my-region> -ProfileName MyProfile
```

and then:

```
Write-S3Object -Bucket <Bucket> -Key <Key> -File <File> -ProfileName MyProfile
```

The Issue gets really weird.

Example 1:
Script G and H are identical except for the filename. They do the exact same task.
Script A calls G saves output as a file and uploads th file to S3 no problem.
Script H has never uploaded except on saturdays for 2 weeks.

Example 2:
80% of the called Scripts worked every single day for 2 weeks. The 20% worked around 2 - 8 times in total each. But no matter how often the Script failed every single Script uploaded saturdays.

Example 3: Script I tried to upload at 17:30 but got the Error "No credentials specified". Script J uploaded 20mins later and no problem.

My guess is that I have misunderstood the documentation at some point, but it seems like this should work right?

Answer (score 0):

That error either means one of two things:

1. Your AWS Credentials are not being passed to the script or during run-time
2. There are some IAM issues with your AWS account

You mention that you have a script calling multiple scripts, have you tried setting the AWS credential on every script? Also, if you can, could you post your parent script that calls the others as well?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Script A is the parent Script and all AWS related code is posted above. The other Scripts don't have anything AWS related, they just return an object to the parent. Thats why the error is so weird.